# Insertion of 2016-08-29-23.17.147253 timestamp data in db2 table

Tags: db2

How can I insert `2016-08-29-23.17.147253`  in db2 timestamp column?

```
INSERT INTO TEST  VALUES (2015,2016-08-29-23.17.147253,  5000 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
```

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is working fine, `2016-08-29-23.17.147253` not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format of timestamp seems incorrect. It must be "*A timestamp is a seven-part value representing a date and time by year, month, day, hour, minute, second, and microsecond*". Also, enclose the timestamp value in single quotes in INSERT statement. For more infor check :
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/intro/src/tpc/db2z_datetimetimestamp.html

Answer (score 0):

Try with quote like this:

```
    INSERT INTO TEST  VALUES (2015, '2016-08-29-23.17.147253',  5000 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
```

Comment: Only adding the apostrophes as string delimiter [to the second expression in the VALUES() from the OP] is of little help, without also a proper format of the TIMESTAMP string constant [to avoid sqlcode=-180].  See [accepted] answer by bp89.